# Unable to properly data bind in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm a newbie to WPF and data binding and after hours of binging and searching Stackoverflow I have not been able to find a comprehensive solution. I am trying to display text on a TextBlock control using data binding on my KinectWindow.xaml:

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="InitText" 
            TextWrapping="Wrap" 
            Text="{Binding Source=ScanInitTextA, 
                           Path=ScanInitTextA, 
                           UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

The complimentary KinectWindow.xaml.cs class has the following property:

```
string ScanInitText = "Preparing for Initial Scan.";    
 string ScanInitTextA
    { get { return (ScanInitText) ; }
        set { ScanInitTextA = value; }
    }
```

I've made numerous attempts, either by binding the property directly from the class or from the xaml. I usually get this error when trying to do anything:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ScanInitTextA' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=1828304777)'. 
BindingExpression:Path=ScanInitTextA; 
DataItem='String' (HashCode=1828304777); 
target element is 'TextBlock' (Name='InitText'); 
target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

From what I understand, ScanInitTextA cannot be found in the object String?

Finally, I know that when I try a similar approach from a different class (that isn't KinectWindow.xaml.cs, by referencing the class in the xaml and changing the binding source to the name of that class), the data binding does work, but for other reasons I'd prefer to do it through this class.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: your understanding is right - just check your binding. i think you mix up Path and Source. try to remove the Source=ScanInitTextA

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="InitText" 
                TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                Text="{Binding  Path=ScanInitTextA}"
```

Error message says that you trying to find property `ScanInitTextA` on the string object itself. I think the `Source` for current `TextBlock` was assigned before (maybe as `DataContext`).

Comment: I tried that initially but it wouldn't work because I have a DataContext in my code for something else (or at least that what I think) which is why I added a Binding source.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
     <TextBlock x:Name="InitText" 
        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
        Text="{Binding  Path=ScanInitTextA, 
                       UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I tried initially, but I had a datacontext for something else so I think that's why it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set the `DataContext` of you view to self then giving `Source` is wrong. Just update your binding as:

```
 <TextBlock x:Name="InitText" 
        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
        Text="{Binding Path=ScanInitTextA, 
                       UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: That's what I tried initially but I get the same output error.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

What is needed is a way to bind to the property of the main window. Here is a way to do that binding

```
<Window x:Name="KinectWindow"
        Title="My Kinect Show"
        ...>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ScanInitTextA, ElementName=KinectWindow}" />
```

Note that you will still need to make ScanInitTextA do a property changed notification if you expect its value will be changed by something and that change needs to be displayed *automatically*. See #1 and #2 below.

---

### Original Advice to Adhere to MVVM type system and put the VM on the Data Context of the Window

1. First off whatever class is holding ScanInitTextA needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and **make ScanInitTextA public**.
2. Secondly a better binding methodology is done by setting the page's data context to the class which has the INotifyPropertyChanged. That is done because it centralizes all of your data to be shown in one location and that a page's data context is inherited by all the controls, so at that point each of the page's controls simply bind to the property name. This is basic MVVM where the VM (view model) has the INotifyPropertyChanged.

## Example

We want to show `Members`, a list of strings, on our page in a list box. Ultimately our binding will be just `{Binding Members}`.

### View Model

```
public class MainVM : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
 
    private List<string> _Members;
 
    public List<string> Members 
    { 
        get { return _Members; }
        set { _Members = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } 
    }
    public MainVM()
    {
        // Simulate Asychronous access, such as to a db.
 
        Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        Members = new List<string>() {"Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Omega"};
                        MemberCount = Members.Count;
                    });
    }
    /// <summary>Event raised when a property changes.</summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
 
    /// <summary>Raises the PropertyChanged event.</summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property that has changed.</param>
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
 
}
}
```

### Page Codebehind

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
 
        public MainVM ViewModel { get; set; }
 
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
 
            // Set the windows data context so all controls can have it.
            DataContext = ViewModel = new MainVM();
 
        }
 
    }
```

### Page Xaml with binding

```
   <ListBox Name="lbData"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Members}"
                SelectionMode="Multiple"
                Margin="10" />
```

This example is taken from my blog article:

[Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding.](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017)

Comment: Hi, I forgot to include it here but the property was already public and INotifyPropertyChanged was already implemented. Also I would use datacontext but I'm already using datacontext (or rather, the code the Microsoft sample is using data context for something else) which is why I am trying to use source.

Comment: @Gaessaki Ok, on MS using the datacontext; whatever is the current datacontext, make it contain the Microsoft needed properties and your needed properties. There is no rule that says that a data context only has to have one property.

Comment: Do you have a resource on how to do this? If I use datacontext again for some reason it seems to override the original datacontext setting by MS.

Comment: Here is the code if it's any help (took out lines to fit char lim):

`public KinectWidow()
      {
            this.viewModel = new KinectWindowViewModel();
            this.viewModel.KinectSensorManager = new KinectSensorManager();
            Binding sensorBinding = new Binding("KinectSensor");
            sensorBinding.Source = this;
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(this.viewModel.KinectSensorManager, KinectSensorManager.KinectSensorProperty, sensorBinding);          
            this.DataContext = this.viewModel;            
            InitializeComponent();
           
        }`

Comment: Is KinectWindowViewModel() something you can change?

Comment: @Gaessaki Does the window have a name? See my update for binding to a window name.

Comment: I can't change KinectWindowVieModel() unfortunately or the Kinect won't update. the Window's name is KinectWindow. I'll try that and get back to you.

Comment: @Gaessaki See my update on how to bind to the window with a property of ScanInitTextA.